# передать пароль в терминал linux из скрипта

Tags: linux, bash, password

Есть скрипт на `bash`:

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 65
```

как можно сделать так, чтобы пароль вводился автоматом из скрипта.

P.S.: Данный код написан мной и для меня проблема безопасности не стоит.

Comment: Используйте `expect`, но можно разрешить безпарольный вызов из конфигурации `sudo` (почти как в ответе, но я бы ограничил только определённый набор команд, а не всё подряд).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
echo mYsuperPassWorD|sudo -S iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j TTL --ttl-set 65
```

Читайте хелпы и маны, они рулез!

```
$ sudo --help

...

Параметры:
  -A, --askpass                 использовать
                                вспомогательную программу
                                для ввода пароля
  -b, --background              выполнить команду в фоновом
                                режиме
  -B, --bell                    ring bell when prompting
  -C, --close-from=num          закрыть все дескрипторы
                                файлов >= num
  -E, --preserve-env            сохранить пользовательское
                                окружение при выполнении
                                команды
      --preserve-env=list       preserve specific environment variables
  -e, --edit                    редактировать файлы вместо
                                выполнения команды
  -g, --group=group             выполнить команду от имени
                                или ID указанной группы
  -H, --set-home                установить для переменной
                                HOME домашний каталог
                                указанного пользователя
  -h, --help                    показать справку и выйти
  -h, --host=host               выполнить команду на узле
                                (если поддерживается
                                модулем)
  -i, --login                   запустить оболочку входа в
                                систему от имени указанного
                                пользователя; также можно
                                задать команду
  -K, --remove-timestamp        полностью удалить файл timestamp
  -k, --reset-timestamp         объявить недействительным
                                файл timestamp
  -l, --list                    показать список прав
                                пользователя или проверить
                                заданную команду; в длинном
                                формате используется дважды
  -n, --non-interactive         автономный режим без не
                                вывода запросов
                                пользователю
  -P, --preserve-groups         сохранить вектор группы
                                вместо установки целевой
                                группы
  -p, --prompt=prompt           использовать указанный
                                запрос пароля
  -S, --stdin                   читать пароль из
                                стандартного ввода

...
```

Но лучше сразу запускать скрипт от рутового пользователя. Например из cron или юнита/таймера systemd.

Answer (score 3):

Если вопрос стоит в том, чтобы не вводить пароль `sudo`, тогда нужно просто его настроить, для этого добавляется в файл `/etc/sudoers` строка:

```
%sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Пароль больше не будет запрашиваться.